# AdvanceDataGrid nodes collapse on refresh

Tags: apache-flex, advanceddatagrid

I have an AdvancedDataGrid which Im attemping to update with data from a web service that I poll once very 10 seconds. Im using a HierarchicalData object to provide data to the grid.  The update seems to work fine, except that on each update, any nodes that were expanded are collapsed when the grid is refreshed.  Stranger still, when I dig down into the bowels of the thing and look at the contents of the HierarchicalCollectionView that backs the grid, I can see that the openNodes property correctly contains the nodes that I opened, but those nodes are not shown as open on the grid...the state seems inconsistent.  Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I try and steer clear of that component.  I think your best bet is to extend it and implement the functionality you need (you will probably end up overriding a good amount of logic to get what you need).

You already know that you can utilize the openNodes property...

I know this answer doesn't help you immediately, but you will thank yourself later if you take the time to roll out your own component.